# GetUserTimeline always returns my own timeline

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, timeline

I am using python-twitter library, but I am unable to get the timeline of a specified user.
Example

```
print [s.text for s in api.GetUserTimeline('@BarackObama')]
```

returns:

```
[u'test']
```

which is my last tweet (api is the object returned by tweeter.Api(...)).

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**: The complete code:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',consumer_secret='',access_token_key='',access_token_key='')
print [s.text for s in api.GetUserTimeline('BarackObama')]
```

Comment: What does len(api.GetUserTimeline('@BarackObama')) return?

Comment: It would also be useful to post all of your code (providing it's a short, self-contained example)

Comment: Are you logging in as yourself first? What happens if you just import the module, set up an api object and run the line of code above?

Comment: Does it work with `GetUserTimeline('BarackObama')` (without the @ sign) ?

Comment: @Talvalin: len()=1 (my tweet)

Comment: @André: GetUserTimeline('BarackObama') also returns my own tweet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead (screen_name will accept `@BarackObama`, `BarackObama` or `barackobama`):

```
print [s.text for s in api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name='@BarackObama')]
```

(c.f. [`GetUserTimeline` test code in twitter_test.py](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter_test.py#L386) - which is to say that the documentation needs to be updated)